# How to solve this biparametral recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a problem that reduces to solving the following recurrence relation:

$$X(2, 1) = 1, \ \ \ X(n, 0) = 0, \ \ \ X(n, k \geq n) = 0$$
$$X(n, 0 < k < n) = \frac{k-1}{n-1} X(n-1, k-1) + \left(1 - \frac{k}{n-1}\right) X(n-1, k)$$

When I am given the final answer, it's easy for me to prove that it's correct -- I can do it either by induction, or by simply plugging it in and showing the two sides are equal.

However, what I don't know is how to systematically *derive* the final answer in the first place.

How do I solve this recurrence relation?

Comment: A double index power series would do the job.

Comment: @AlexR.: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by that and how did you suddenly come up with it? (Again, I'm looking to see if there's a way to derive it systematically, i.e. without having to guess-and-check.)